# Strange behaviour snprintf c

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

After a few weeks playing with C, I now hate it.

I'm now trying to pass arguments to another program using execl, and the formatting of the arguments does weird things:

```
int select[2], result[2];
char str_w,str_r;

snprintf(&str_w, 2, "%d", select[1]);
snprintf(&str_r, 2, "%d", result[0]);
printf("%d %d %s %s\n", select[1], result[0], &str_w, &str_r);

execl("./recive.x","./recive.x",&str_w,&str_r,(char *)NULL);
```

What is important here is the snprintf: I'm trying to convert a number in a vector to a string. The number will be smaller than 10. When I execute this, the result of the printf shown is:

```
5 6  6
```

Which means that there's a number (5) in select[1], there's a number (6) in result[0] and result[0] is converted to string properly but select[1] no.

What the hell is that behaviour!!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *After a few weeks playing with C, I now hate it* Perhaps you should stop playing and learn about it first ?

Comment: While I'm playing with it, I find some difficult points that make me stop, think and learn, so while I'm playing, I learn.

Comment: If you really spent a few weeks and are making these mistakes then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After a few weeks playing with C, I now hate it.

This is not an uncommon reaction.  A third of my intro CS class *changed majors*, citing difficulty with C (it's a horrible teaching language).  It took me several years to adequately wrap my head around it, but once I did I came to appreciate it.

```
char str_w,str_r;

snprintf(&str_w, 2, "%d", select[1]);
snprintf(&str_r, 2, "%d", result[0]);
```

This is your main problem; `str_w` and `str_r` are only large enough to hold a single `char` value, not strings (which would require *at least* 2 characters).  Instead, you need to declare `str_w` and `str_r` as *arrays* of `char`, large enough to hold the string representation of the largest `int` you'll be expecting, plus space for a sign (if the value is negative), plus the 0 terminator.  For example, if you weren't limiting the value on `select` or `result`:

```
#define MAX_DIGITS 20 // max decimal digits for 64-bit integer
#define SIZE MAX_DIGITS+2 // 2 extra for sign and 0 terminator

char str_w[SIZE], str_r[SIZE]; 

sprintf(str_w, "%d", select[1]);
sprintf(str_r, "%d", result[0]);
```

By making your target arrays large enough for any possible input, you don't have to worry about overflow.  Yes, you suffer a little internal fragmentation, and depending on your application that may or may not be an issue.  But I just like keeping things simple.

If you *know for a fact* that your `select` and `result` arrays will never hold values outside the range 0..10, then you can set SIZE to 3 (up to 2 digits plus 0 terminator).

> Which means that there's a number (5) in select[1], there's a number (6) in result[0] and result[0] is converted to string properly but select[1] no.
>
> What the hell is that behaviour!!

Since you passed an address to a buffer that wasn't large enough to hold the result, the behavior is *undefined*, meaning the compiler isn't obligated to warn you that you're doing something dangerous.

Here's what's *most likely* happening (since the behavior is undefined, *any* sequence of events is possible, but I think this is a reasonable interpretation of the result).  First of all, assume your variables are laid out in memory as follows:

```
Item        Address        Value
----        -------        -----
str_r       0xffec1230     ??
str_w       0xffec1231     ??
            0xffec1232     ??
```

`str_w` and `str_r` are allocated to consecutive bytes, and their initial value is indeterminate.  After the first `snprintf` to `str_w`, your memory now looks like this:

```
Item        Address        Value
----        -------        -----
str_r       0xffec1230     ??
str_w       0xffec1231     '5'
            0xffec1232     0
```

`snprintf` will write a trailing 0 terminator to the buffer; in this case, it writes the terminator to the byte following `str_w`.  After the second `sprintf` call, memory now looks like this:

```
Item        Address        Value
----        -------        -----
str_r       0xffec1230     '6'
str_w       0xffec1231     0
            0xffec1232     0
```

The second `snprintf` call wrote the 0 terminator to the byte following `str_r`, which just happens to be `str_w`; you wound up clobbering the value written to it previously.  That's why you see the `str_r` string but not the `str_w` string.

Answer (score 2):

A call to sprintf must provide a buffer for the printed data, enough to fit the entire output. You are passing a pointer to a single char, so the output clearly does not fit.

```
char str_w[2];
snprintf(str_w, 2, "%d", select[0]);
```

A better way to convert a one-digit number to a string is as follows:

```
char res[2];
res[0]=num+'0';
res[1]=0;
```

Note the single quotes around the first zero: the idea is to add the code of the zero character to the one-digit number.

Comment: But why on earth one works and the other doesn't!!! If it is wrong, it shouldn't work in any. That's what confuses me and makes me angry.

Comment: @markmb The reason the first one works is that there happens to be an extra char space after str_w - namely, the one allocated to str_r. Still, it is undefined behavior, but it does not crash, essentially, by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

With `char` you define the only one byte variable. It must me an array of `char`s.